# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.time'

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime

I have a pandas DataFrame:

```
In [33]: df
Out[33]:
                         userId          2021-01-29          2021-01-30          2021-01-01
0                Nl3AG93Ss7L5aj            09:00:00                 NaN                 NaN
1                           NaN                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN
2                AbVpBHdfrI5aj1            12:10:00                 NaN                 NaN
3                           NaN                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN
4                           NaN                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN
5               sad9283ds7L5aj1                 NaN            15:35:00            22:22:00
6                           NaN                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN
7                           NaN                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN
8                           NaN                 NaN                 NaN                 NaN
```

I need to get the date and time the script started working, but I get the error:

```
TypeError Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-40-7ed51ff0c115> in <module>
      1 for column in df.columns.tolist():
----> 2     for  i in df.loc[df[column].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, datetime.time))][column]: print(column + i)
      3

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.time'
```

Also I can output the schedule without merging:

```
In [22]: for column in df.columns.tolist():
    ...:     for  time in df.loc[df[column].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, datetime.time))][column]: print(column, time)
    ...:
2021-01-29 00:00:00 09:00:00
2021-01-29 00:00:00 12:10:00
2021-01-30 00:00:00 15:35:00
2021-01-01 00:00:00 22:22:00
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try converting the things into strings and just using the `+` as string concat...

```
for column in df.columns.tolist():
    for  i in df.loc[df[column].apply(lambda x: isinstance(x, datetime.time))][column]: print(column.strftime("%Y-%m-%d”) +" "+ i.strftime("%H:%M:%S”))
```